# matplotlib set_rmax and set_rticks not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, polar-coordinates

I am using python3 in an anaconda jupyter notebook and am plotting graphs in polar coordinates.  I want all the graphs to have the same rmax and rticks, but when I set them, they are not applied and the points aren't plotted correctly.  Here is my code, without and then with them.

```
%pylab inline
X = asarray([[0.23, 0.73],[0.22, 1.16],[0.18, 1.86],[0.17, 2.39],[0.24, 2.74],[0.16, 3.43],[0.16, 3.87],[0.13, 4.39],[0.14, 5.00],[0.17, 5.53]])

ax0 = subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax0.plot(X[:,1], X[:,0], 'r+')
show()

ax1 = subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax1.set_rmax(0.8)
ax1.set_rticks([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
ax1.plot(X[:,1], X[:,0], 'r+')
show()
```

Here are the plots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are first setting the `rmax` and then plotting your polar chart. So once you plot, the limits are automatically adjusted and your set `rmax` and `rticks` are overwritten.

The solution is to *first* plot and *then* set the `rmax` and `rticks` as shown below.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax1.plot(X[:,1], X[:,0], 'r+')
ax1.set_rmax(0.8)
ax1.set_rticks([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
```

[image]